# Best practice to handle batch of long api calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm designing a user interface to upload a list of users (email, name, etc...) in which at the end of the process, each of these users are inserted my database and also received an email.

The backend api that handles this task is built in ruby on rails.

There is currently no limit to the size of the input, therefore I want to provide a way for the UI user to cancel the remaining jobs throughout the uploading process without cancel the jobs that is already sent.

I also want to provide on the GUI real time status on which jobs are being worked on, already finished.

In addition, I want to make sure the number of jobs spawned to simultaneously handle the jobs is limited so that other users on the server will not be affected.

With that said... and with my limited backend / javascript knowledge, what I am thinking I would do is to spawn individual ajax calls for each user (or possibly a grouping of several users), using java to limit at any time only X ajax calls can be run simultaneously (I'm  hoping this is possible) and when each call returns I will update the UI to reflect the status of the job and then spawn another one for the next set of job until the whole thing is finished. If the UI user wish to cancel they can with the completed job remain complete.

Would this be advisable or is there a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would make sense to let a background job to handle this. Something like resque, sidekiq or delayed_job ? The user can upload the entire list (which shouldn't take much time) and you can process them "at leisure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use sidekiq for tasks like this. It does exactly what you're looking for.

You set up a number of workers, which are threads on your server. Then, as POSTs or other requests come in from the UI, you queue each one up as a job in sidekiq, and immediately return status back to the browser, so they don't have to wait around wondering if something is going to succeed, hang forever, or get timed out by the web server.

Later on, the job gets processed asynchronously.  It can update status in the database for reporting.

Here is an example of worker that runs under sidekiq:

```
class PageFetcher
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform page_id
    page = Page.find(page_id)
    path = Page.absolute_path

    # Do some big, long, error-prone thing with external depencies:
    File.binwrite(path, open(page.source_url).read)
    saved_size = File.size(path)

    if page.expected_file_size != saved_size.to_s
      bad_path = path + '.bad'
      File.rename(path, bad_path)

      # Raise an error, and sidekiq will automatically wait a while and try again later:
      raise IOError, "Could not cache #{page.source_url} to #{path}. " +
        "File size is #{saved_size}, expected #{page.file_size}. "
    end


    # update some status field, so this success can be reported:
    page.make_status_cached!

    # do something else that depends on this success:
    page.notify_page_indexer
  end
end
```

When you receive a new request, create a new Page, then queue up its processing like this:

```
Page.perform_async(self.id)
```

Voila!  That's it.